# How can I copy the object in the popup when inspecting a breakpoint without having to expand all the properties first?

Tags: google-chrome, breakpoints, devtools

When I am troubleshooting with Chrome DevTools, in the Sources tab, and have breakpoints set, I often want to inspect the element at that point and would like to be able to copy and paste the complete, expanded object, without having to expand all the properties first.
If I inadvertently mouse off the popup, it contracts the property dropdowns.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UGOfB.png)